# Convert one dataframes to another using groupBy operations on the cell values

Tags: python, dataframe

This is my dataframe. Each value of the cells of candidates[A,B,C,D] are choices given by voters ranging from {1,2,3,4}

```
number of   A   B   C   D
voters                  
   1        1   1   1   1
   1        1   1   2   1
   1        1   4   1   2
   1        1   4   1   1
   1        1   1   4   1
   2        1   3   3   1
   1        1   1   1   4
   3        1   1   1   4
```

```
import pandas as pd

import numpy as np

df= pd.read_csv('demoIRV.csv',encoding='latin1')

finalData = {}

for i in df.columns[1:]:
    total = 0;
    total = df.groupby(i)['number of voters'].sum()
    print(total)
```

I am getting o/p in this format:

```
A
1    11
Name: number of voters, dtype: int64
B
1    7
3    2
4    2
Name: number of voters, dtype: int64
C
1    7
2    1
3    2
4    1
Name: number of voters, dtype: int64
D
1    6
2    1
4    4
Name: number of voters, dtype: int64
```

I need the data to be stored in another dataframe with same columns, with number of voters in its column

sample o/p:

```
Choice  A   B   C   D
  1     11  7   7   6
  2     0   0   1   1
  3     0   2   2   0
  4     0   2   1   4
```

Comment: The beauty of dataframe and pandas is that you dont need to iterate through each row and column to process them. You can directly apply the groupby against the entire dataframe by providing the list of columns you want to groupby.

Comment: I tried this but i still dont get the expected o/p: ````df = df.groupby(['A','B','C','D'])['number of voters'].sum()````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a version of your own solution where we munge the resulting dataframes together

```
(pd.concat([
    pd.DataFrame(df.groupby(c)['number of voters'].sum())
    .reset_index()
    .drop(columns = c)
    .rename(columns = {'number of voters':c}) 
    for c in df.set_index('number of voters').columns],axis=1)
.fillna(0))
```

produces

```
    A   B   C   D
0   11  7.0 7   6.0
1   0.0 2.0 1   1.0
2   0.0 2.0 2   4.0
3   0.0 0.0 1   0.0
```

To explain, we call groupby/sum on each column as you do, put these in a list, then rename columns and finally concatenate

Comment: Should I include this part inside a for loop?

Comment: @ShreyaB no -- this should replace the for loop and do the whole thing

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you correctly this should do its job.

```
df = df.groupby('number of voters')[['A','B','C','D']].sum()
new_df = pd.DataFrame(df)
```

You don't even have to iterate anything through

Comment: it's df instead of stack, my bad it's a typo. let me know if I helped if so, thumbs up

Comment: No it doesnt work . It doesnt result in expected o/p. I want to group by column each column [A, B, C,D] and add the values in 'number of voters'

Answer (score 0):

@Piterbarg provided you the results already. It didn't have the choices.

Here's another way to do this. The below version is not the most optimized solution but is an option for you to use if you are looking for a way to get to your answer.

```
#first find the unique values from columns 'A', 'B', 'C', and 'D'
dfX = (pd.DataFrame({'Choice':df.iloc[:,1:].values.ravel()})
         .sort_values('Choice')
         .drop_duplicates(subset=['Choice'])
         .reset_index(drop=True))

#Then set the sum to zero
dfX['A'] = 0
dfX['B'] = 0
dfX['C'] = 0
dfX['D'] = 0

#iterate thru the unique values and find the count of votes for each unique value
for _,vdfX in dfX.iterrows():
    for _,vdf in df.iterrows():
        if vdf['A'] == vdfX['Choice']: vdfX['A'] += vdf['number of voters']
        if vdf['B'] == vdfX['Choice']: vdfX['B'] += vdf['number of voters']
        if vdf['C'] == vdfX['Choice']: vdfX['C'] += vdf['number of voters']
        if vdf['D'] == vdfX['Choice']: vdfX['D'] += vdf['number of voters']
        
print (dfX)
```

The output of this is:

```
   Choice   A  B  C  D
0       1  11  7  7  6
1       2   0  0  1  1
2       3   0  2  2  0
3       4   0  2  1  4
```